# Binary Search in Fortran 95

Tags: search, binary, fortran

I try to implement a binary search in Fortran 95 with a recursive function.

My error message is: /usr/bin/timeout: the monitored command dumped core

Does anyone have an idea how I could solve this problem?

The return value should be 2 for this little programm.

In addition: How can I expand my code to return the position number of the array "ar" to know where I can add my new element (i.e "2.9")? In case of 2.9 it should return 2. Another example, if I take 7.3 instead of 2.9 it should return 6 (between 7.0 and 8.0 of array "ar").

```
program h
   real, dimension(7) :: ar
   integer :: s
   real :: outp
   ar = (/2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0/)
   s = sizeof(ar)
   outp = findAr(ar, 1, s, 3.0)
   print*, outp
end program h

recursive function findAr(ar, l, r, x) result(a)
        real, dimension(size(ar)), intent(in)  :: ar
        integer, intent(in) :: l, r
        real, intent(in) :: x
        integer :: midd
        real :: a
        if (r >= 1) then
            midd = l + (r - 1) / 2
            if (ar(midd) == x) then
                a = midd
            else if (ar(midd) > x) then
                a = findAr(ar, l, midd - 1, x)
                else
                a = findAr(ar, midd + 1, r, x)
            end if
        end if
end function findAr
```

Comment: `real, dimension(size(ar)), intent(in) :: ar` is trying to say 'declare ar to be an array which has size given by whatever its size is'. That's not a nice thing to say to the poor compiler. What is it that you want to happen. I guess you mean `dimension(:)` or even `dimension(*)` but it would be helpful if you can clarify.

Comment: If dimension( : ) you'll also need an interface in scope, and I think you do for recursive routines as well - so stick all subprograms in modules, and then you won't have to worry about what the current rules are.

Comment: If you are using a recursive function, you need an explicit interface.

Comment: Certainly you did in Fortran 90-2008. Given as of 2018 all routines are by default recursive I wasn't sure if the requirement had been relaxed. But it is definitely best practice to have an interface in scope when calling any routine, irrespective of whether it is used recursively or not

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error can be resolved as specified by the comments to your questions.

---

Concerning your 2nd question: How to extend your code for search values in between the array elements. One could ask in the same manner for values outside of your array (e.g. smaller than its minimum).

The following code is not using recursive functions nor is it an extension of your code.
You should keep in mind that unnecessary function calls create some overhead and could result in performance loss.

```
module bin_search_m
  implicit none
contains
  function bin_search(x, x1) result(i)
    !! find index of nearest value in sorted array
    real,              intent(in) :: x(:)
      !! sorted array
    real,              intent(in) :: x1
      !! value to find
    integer                       :: i
      !! return array index

    integer :: i0, i1

    ! starting interval is the whole array
    i0 = 1
    i1 = size(x)

    ! test if x1 is outside of interval [x(1), x(end)]
    if (x1 <= x(i0)) then
      i = i0
      return
    end if
    if (x1 >= x(i1)) then
      i = i1
      return
    end if

    ! binary search
    do while (i1 > (i0 + 1))
      i = (i1 + i0) / 2
      if      (x(i) < x1) then
        i0 = i
      else if (x(i) > x1) then
        i1 = i
      else
        return
      end if
    end do

    ! pick index of value that is closer
    i = merge(i0, i1, ((2 * x1) < (x(i0) + x(i1))))
  end function
end module
```

Comment: Hi jack
Thank you very much for the help. I tried to implement your code as following and have some troubles to make it run. I do really not know why it does not work. Can you maybe look at my code and help me again?

Comment: program hello
 implicit none
 real, dimension(7) :: ar
 real :: val
 integer :: outp
 ar = (/2.d0, 3.d0, 4.d0, 5.d0, 7.d0, 8.d0, 9.d0/)
 val = 3.d0
 outp = findInAr(ar, val)
 print*, outp
end program hello

Comment: integer function findInAr(x, x1)
 implicit none
 real, intent(in) :: x(:)
 real, intent(in) :: x1
 integer :: i0, i1, a
 i0 = 1
 i1 = size(x)

 if (x1 <= x(i0)) then
  findInAr = i0
  return
 end if
 if (x1 >= x(i1)) then
  findInAr = i1
  return
 end if

 do while (i1 > (i0 + 1))
  a = (i1 + i0) / 2
  if (x(a) < x1) then
   i1 = 1
  else if (x(a) > x1) then
   i1 = 1
  else
   return
  end if
 end do
 findInAr = a
end function

Comment: Either append to your question here or even better: create a new question. The comment section is not a great spot to discuss code.
Did my answer help in anyway?